# Disable all interaction except click

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I'm trying to generate a chart with Dygraph library without any interaction available (no zoom, no move,...) but still clickable.

I now how to remove all interaction callbacks with something like

```
interactionModel: {}
```

or

```
interactionModel: { 
   <event>: function (event, g, context) {Dygraph.cancelEvent(event);}
}
```

but prototype is different from the one used for clickcallback which is

```
clickCallback: function(e, x, points) { <my code> }
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set

```
interactionModel: Dygraph.Interaction.nonInteractiveModel_
```

This should prevent interaction while still allowing click events to pass through to your `clickCallback`.

It's not clear why this interaction model is private: it seems useful!